# caching images on UITableViewCells with AlamofireImages in my Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofireimage

I'm writing a `Swift` app that displays photos fetched from server on each cell of my UITableViewController.

So far my code looks as follows:

```
func tableView(detailsPanel: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = detailsPanel.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! DetailsCell

    let test:SingleTest =  self.items[indexPath.row] as! SingleTest
    if(test.photo != "") {
        cell.myPhoto.af_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: test.photo)!)
    }

}
```

Now, the problem is that not every cell has a photo stored in `cell.photo`. Some of them are empty strings (`""`). In that situation when I quickly scroll through the table view, I see that those empty `UIImageView`s are filled with photos from other cells.

The quick fix for that seems to be adding an `else` block:

```
if(test.photo != "") {
    cell.myPhoto.af_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: test.photo)!)
} //this one below:
else {
    cell.myPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "placeholderImg")
}
```

Now whenever there is no photo, the `placeHolderImg` will be displayed there. But... is there a way of avoiding it and just do not display anything there? And by not displaying anything I mean not displaying images from different cells?

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing your cells, thus the cell will still use the previous image that it has loaded unless you set it to nil or a placeholder image. However I believe you do not need to use an if statement. You can use the placeholderImage parameter of af_setImageWithURL.

```
cell.myPhoto.af_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: test.photo)!, placeholderImage: image)
```

Comment: can you tell me how can I set it to nil? I tried with writing in `else` statement: `cell.myPhoto = nil` but then when I scroll through the list I'm getting error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`